# Can the MVC's parameter list be dynamic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

If:

```
http://mySite/Users/9055
```

returns a db record where UserID=9055 (via the userController.getUserID method)

And:

```
http://mySite/Users/Smith
```

returns the same record via the userController.getUserName method

Isn't it reasonable to code a controller method that parses the either input?

Seems like a great option to users - the url as a means of navigating - as long as the top-level (controller) is broad yet focused enough (Users, Products, Billing, Reports) how do we parse for (so we can search on) any of several different datatypes?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have a string parameter for controller's action and then do `int.TryParse` to check if it is integer. if not assume that it is string